# Naive bayes computation of denominator

Tags: probability, bayesian, naive-bayes, checking

I'm wondering about the denominator in this computation :

```
P(Banana|Long, Sweet and Yellow) 
      P(Long|Banana) * P(Sweet|Banana) * P(Yellow|Banana) * P(banana)
    = _______________________________________________________________
                      P(Long) * P(Sweet) * P(Yellow)
```

Which is from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059594/a-simple-explanation-of-naive-bayes-classification)

I don't know that it is valid to convert

```
P(long, sweet, yellow)
```

to

```
P(long)P(sweet)P(yellow)
```

The reason that I'm confused is that we have conditional independence, rather than complete independence.

Or is this valid here?

## edit - text example

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It isn't correct exactly for the reason you realized. The *evidence* calculation should be:
$$P(L,S,Y)=\sum_{B'\in \{Banana,Orange,Other\}} P(L|B')P(S|B')P(Y|B')P(B')$$

However, the classification is correct because the *evidence* is not important in Naive Bayes classifier since it is common for all classes.

Comment: Thank you, perhaps the other post should be edited as it seems to be quite popular? ( I found it via google search ). I'm not sure how that works between stacks  and whether this suggestion is appropriate

Comment: I can post a comment there, but don’t know it’d be effective or not; it’s probably been upvoted by many with elementary probability knowledge.