# On the denominator of Bayes and Naive Bayes

Tags: probability, bayesian, conditional-probability, naive-bayes

There are many question on the topic but I think the comparison below is harder to find.

Let us assume that all variables in this example are binary for the sake of simplicity. The typical academic Bayes formula given two random variables is the following:

$$
\Pr(A|B) =  \frac{\Pr(B|A)  \Pr(A)}{\Pr(B|A)  \Pr(A) + \Pr(B| \overline{A})  \Pr(\overline{A})}
$$

However, searches on this site suggest that the denominator in Naive Bayes given three random vars is the following:

$$
\Pr(A|B,C) =  \frac{\Pr(B|A) \Pr(C|A) \Pr(A)}{ \Pr(C|B)\Pr(B) + \Pr(B|C)\Pr(C) } 
$$

Where is the $A$ r.v. in the denominator of the Naive Bayes?

Comment: About to type an answer. Meanwhile, can you link to a post that gives the formula you saw?

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy There is a chance I misunderstood their answer  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/404487/naive-bayes-computation-of-denominator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The question you linked to](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/404487/naive-bayes-computation-of-denominator) is by someone curious about an incorrect formula they found. The answer corrects it. The corrected formula does include $A$ in the denominator.

In your notation, the formula from the answer includes $A$ and is:

$$
\Pr(A \mid B, C) = \frac{
\Pr(B \mid A) \Pr(C \mid A) \Pr(A)
}{
\Pr(B \mid A) \Pr(C \mid A) \Pr(A) + \Pr(B \mid \overline A) \Pr(C \mid \overline A) \Pr(\overline A)
}
$$

More in line with their notation, this is equivalent to

$$
\Pr(A \mid B, C) = \frac{
\Pr(B \mid A) \Pr(C \mid A) \Pr(A)
}{
\sum_{A' \in \{A, \overline A\}}\Pr(B \mid A') \Pr(C \mid A') \Pr(A')
}
$$

Note that they make a conditional independence assumption. $B$ and $C$ are conditionally independent given $A$. That's why we can write $P(A, B, C)$ as $P(B \mid A) P(C \mid A) P(A)$ instead of $P(B \mid A, C) P(C \mid A) P(A)$.

Comment: Got it - the notation confused me but this makes sense. Thank you